# The connection was reset afte3r migration on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I trying to move my wordpress to google cloud platform but the website display "The connection was reset" after migration.
Im new to this and i have no idea where can i check the error log.

Comment: Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to your instance using SSH as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools).

Once you locate the related files, you can begin debugging [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) depending on your case scenario. (That is not very clear with the information of your question).

After you have more details I suggest either asking in this forum following the [community guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and adding tag either for Wordpress, GCP or any particular plugin you might be using.